# Make Javascript Function then call it back?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following code work successfully

```
<script>
      $('img').click(function(){
          var z = (this.id);
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
       });
</script>
```

but when I added this function a() it didn't work

```
<script> 
    function a(){ 
       $('img').click(function(){
             var z = (this.id);
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
        });}
 </script>
```

as I want to call it back in another code by function a();

so what should I modify?

Comment: what triggers a? this makes little sense

Comment: Please explain alternate use of `a()` in more detail

Comment: onclick="a();return false;" that is the trigger

Comment: then you dont need `$('img').click(function(){` at all

Comment: you do if the img isn't the element containing the onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the click handler never works, it's because it's not added until or unless or a() function is called. If you want that script to work, change it to

```
<script> 
    function a(){ 
       $('img').click(function(){
             var z = (this.id);
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
        });};
    a();
 </script>
```

Which both declares your function and then wires up the click event when it is called.

Answer (score 0):

you would be better off redoing this slightly as follows if it is for alternate use,  callback is a bit different from what i think you want.

```
<script> 
    function a(var object){ 
         var z = (object.id);
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
    }

    $('img').click(function(){
         a(this);
    });
</script>
```